# How to decrease lines of query to do not change final result in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have query in Teradata SQL like below:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC.SUMMARY AS
(
SELECT
DISTINCT A.NR,
A.DATE,
COUNT(DISTINCT B.ID) AS TRX_CNT,
MAX(CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TRX_AB
FROM BASE AS A
LEFT JOIN TRX_BASE AS B
    ON A.NR = B.NR
    WHERE 1=1
    AND B.TRX_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM'), -6) AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 
    'MM')-1
GROUP BY 1, 2
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(NR);
```

**I need to shrink this code and my question is:**
I need to remove lines that are redundant and do not change the result if they are removed, to make this code easier.
I think that rather all these line are needed but I am not sure.

What can I drop from above code so as to do not change the final result of this code ?

Comment: Why are you concerned about the number of words in your query?  Please clarify what your actual goal is because the word length of a query is not a typical constraint

Comment: I need to remove lines that are redundant and do not change the result if they are removed, to make this code easier

Comment: A sample dataset, and a wanted dataset i would appreciate it

Comment: Since you don't have an error in your query and are only seeking some form of "easier" metric for you code, this might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  The goal of Stack Overflow is to fix errors / problems with code, not to make it "easier" or "better"

Comment: code doesn't run something about ebtween vs between.  so as is the code fails, wouldn't produce a table; rather a syntax error...  You don't need where 1=1.  You're logic around getting 6 momnths of data from today is somewhat faulty becuase between is missspelled and it will bring back 6 months of data for ALL years; seems suspicious... you don't need `as` it's optional. but it makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Also the left join is negated by the where clause using between becuase all records with a null value for the date will be eliminated which is the purpose of a left join to keep such records.  So do you need a left join or is an inner sufficient...

Comment: the only "Redundant" line is where 1=1  you could remove it and the following and; and get the same results.

Comment: xQbert do you think that left join is a problem ? could you wtire correct version of this code ? and why where 1=1 is redundant ?

Comment: 1=1 = True.  it serves no purpose to the SQL statement it will always be true so you're saying return all records not otherwise excluded; which the engine would do by default.

Comment: Do you want all records from Base and only those that match in TRX_BASE?  or only records from BASE that also EXIST in trx_Base.  that determines if it should be an inner or left outer join.

Comment: xQbert so do you think that it is not left join or not ? If not why do you think that it is not left join ? Generaly I think second part of your answer I need to do so - left join

Comment: xQbert ? Could tyou help me ?

Comment: @Matop Why are you using WHERE 1=1?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about code review

Comment: What is this, homework? As stated, the JOIN will effectively be "inner" anyway due to referencing a column from B in the WHERE clause in a way that excludes NULL, so don't need LEFT keyword, also don't need 1=1, and the DISTINCT keyword after the SELECT is redundant because you have GROUP BY for the aggregation. Depending on your system settings, PRIMARY INDEX (NR) might be the default but better to leave it in.

Comment: @maptop As it is written it is behaving like an inner join.  THe question is should it?  If you need all records from Base, regardless if there is a record in TRX base, then what you have will not do that.  if you only want records in base & TRX_BASE that exist in BOTH; then an inner join should be used.  I can't know if it should be left or inner join: that's a business question and depends on WHat you're trying to achieve with the query.  From a maintenance standpoint having something as a LEFT join when you then in a where clause negate it; is not good code.

Comment: also bear in mind, we help on our availability; I'm not in anyway affiliated with stack other than having an account.  I help when I have time, not all the time.  Most others here are like that too.  we have different timezones, lunches, work hours etc.  So the help you get may be cut off abruptly because someone goes to sleep; or lunch; or whatever...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE ABC.SUMMARY AS
(
SELECT
  A.NR,
  A.DATE,
  COUNT(DISTINCT B.ID) TRX_CNT,
  MAX(CASE WHEN B.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) TRX_AB
FROM BASE A
INNER JOIN TRX_BASE B
    ON A.NR = B.NR
WHERE B.TRX_DATE BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 'MM'), -6) AND TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE, 
    'MM')-1
GROUP BY A.NR, A.Date
)
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX(NR);
```

Remaining Concerns:

1. date may/may not be a reserved word.  as such I try and avoid columns like that and alias them out to define what the date is for like Base_Date or something.
2. still unsure if it should be an inner join or left. but as you don't want the nature of the query to change, Inner makes sense as the current query behaves like an inner join. that is becuase if a record existed in base but not in trx_base, it would be eliminated by the B.TRX_Date evaluation as no nulls would be included.

What we removed and why:

1. Distinct on NR... the group by handles it
2. 1=1 this adds no value and makes no changes to data.  it's always true..
3. Group by spelled out. if someone makes a change to code adding a column in the 1st two columns, this will break.
4. Removed AS.. it's optional in SQL Server...
5. CHanged left join to inner as your limit on B.TRX_Date will eliminate all the null values the left join generates: so this is an inner join and changing it doesn't impact results.

Comment: No, TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE,'MM') returns the first day of the month not the month itself. And Primary Index is not necessarily unique (it's different from Primary Key).

Comment: thanks for that fred.  I'ts been too long since I've been in SQL server. and i'm now too use to dealing with date strings and hana functions.